# Run Stored Procedure and Check Value Exists or Not C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, specflow, gherkin

I have this stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE ClientDelete
    @clientid uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    UPDATE Clients SET enabled=1,editDate=GETUTCDATE() WHERE clientid=@clientid
END
```

Using this feature file:

```
     Feature: ClientDelete

Scenario: Client Delete
    Given a clean database
    Given the following Clients table
    | clientid | name    | url          | enabled | lastChangedBy | createDate | editDate   |
    | 1        | Client1 | https://test | true    | test          | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-01 |
    | 2        | Client2 | https://test | true    | test          | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-01 |
    When the "ClientDelete" stored procedure is run with the following parameters
    | name     | value |
    | clientid | 11    |
    Then the following is returned
    | clientid | name    | url          | enabled | lastChangedBy | createDate | editDate   |
    | 1        | Client1 | https://test | false   | test          | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-01 |
    | 2        | Client2 | https://test | true    | test          | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-01 |
```

C# Code:

```cs
 [When(@"the ""(.*)"" stored procedure is run with the following parameters")]
        public void WhenTheStoredProcedureIsRunWithTheFollowingParameters(string procName, Table table)
        {
            using (var con = CreateDBConnection())
            {
                using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = procName;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
                        param.ParameterName = row.Values.First();

                        if (param.ParameterName == "clientids")
                        {
                            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                            param.Value = new List<SqlDataRecord>()
                            {
                                ToSqlDataRecord(new Guid(row.Values.Last()))
                            };
                        }
                        else if (param.ParameterName == "docTypes")
                        {
                            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                            if (row.Values.Last() != "NULL")
                            {
                                param.Value = new List<SqlDataRecord>()
                                {
                                    ToSqlDataRecord(row.Values.Last())
                                };
                            }
                        }
                        else if (row.Values.Last() != "NULL")
                            param.Value = row.Values.Last();
                        else
                            param.Value = DBNull.Value;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                    }

                    var results = new DataTable();
                    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter((SqlCommand)cmd))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(results);
                    }

                    _context.Add("Results", results);
                }
            }
        }
```

```cs
   [Then(@"the following is returned")]
        public void ThenTheFollowingIsReturned(Table table)
        {
            var results = _context.Get<DataTable>("Results");
            Assert.AreEqual(table.Rows.Count, results.Rows.Count);

            for (int i = 0; i < results.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var expectedRow = table.Rows[i];
                var actualRow = results.Rows[i];

                for (int j = 0; j < table.Header.Count; j++)
                {
                    var name = table.Header.ElementAt(j);
                    var type = actualRow[name].GetType();
                    object expectedValue = expectedRow[name];
                    if (expectedValue.ToString().IsNullText())
                        expectedValue = null;
                    else if (type != typeof(DBNull))
                        expectedValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromInvariantString(expectedRow[name]);
                    var actualValue = Convert.IsDBNull(actualRow[name]) ? null : actualRow[name];
                    Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue, name);
                }
            }
        }
```

@Then is not working as it's not returning anything from stored procedure so I want to check if the value updated or exists or not.
I have this too when and then used for multiple stored procedure which returns row data and is working fine, but does not work with add, delete, update.

Note: I need to do without adding output parameter to stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

After the update in your stored procedure add:

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS Result
```

This will return the number of rows affected by the previous update statement. You can then check in your C# code if the Result is > 0.

@@ROWCOUNT documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: thanks for your suggestion it does return now 1 but failed at var type = actualRow[name].GetType(); complaining about column clientid does not belong to table

Comment: i think because of the iteration it's looking for same column name again ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the clients table again in your `Then` step. The `DeleteClient` stored procedure does not return anything, nor does it fill an output variable. Your only recourse is the query the clients table again in `Then the following is returned`. You can use the Table extension method [CompareToSet(...)](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers.html#comparetoset-t) instead of doing the assertions manually yourself.

Comment: i got it clients table records now only failing at GETUTCDATE() function returns current date and time but i can not pass time in feature file. how to validate this time?

Comment: also currently i am using table name but for many delete or update stored procedure i want to use same method not creating 1 for each method which is really larger number. what do you suggest table name as variable or something else?

Comment: @Techie: you might be better off writing these tests in plain old C#.

Comment: can we check GETUTCDATE() function in gherkin file ?